# Transit visa for Saudi Arabia

Tags: visas, transit, transit-visas, saudi-arabia

I have a flight from Los Angeles to Lahore on the 26th with a layover of 3 hours in Jeddah. On my way back to Los Angeles, I have a layover of 19 hours. I tried getting the transit visa, but the website keeps saying that there's an error. Do I need to have the transit visa before I fly out of Los Angeles, or I can take my outbound flight and then get the visa before my return flight, since the long layover is on my way back to Los Angeles.

Comment: You mention USA locations, but in the tags UK and citizen without nationality, can you please clear up your citizenship?

Comment: It must been a typo I meant to type USA

Comment: What is your citizenship? What is your airport-to-airport itinerary?

Comment: Also, what website are you using, and what error specifically does it give?